# How to get \part and paragraphs (text) on the same page (memoir class)?

Tags: memoir

Does someone know how to prevent the "\cleardoublepage" after each part in a memoir class document ?

I don't have the slightets idea how to do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage{lipsum}
\nonzeroparskip
\begin{document}
\part {Test}
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae
Nam
ornare odio metus a mi.

Nam
\end{document}
```

I would like to have my part's and section's titles on the same page.
Thanks

Comment: Exactly what do you want `\part` to do instead? should any text start immediately or on the next page??? Not particularly clear from your question

Comment: Yes sorry. I'am using your theme daleif :). 

I want `\part` like `\section`, that is to say on a single page with the text. So, the text after `\part` should start immediately on the part's title page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
...
{\let\newpage\relax
\part {Test}}
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
...
```

if you need `\part` very often, you can redefine the command.

```
\let\Part\part
\renewcommand\part[2][]{{\let\newpage\relax
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\Part{#2}\else\Part[#1]{#2}\fi}}
\begin{document}
\part {Test}
...
```

Comment: Ah thanks !!! How can I redefine this command ? With renewcommand ?

Comment: see my edited answer.